# Error message whenever alphabet is entered rather than number

Tags: vb.net

I m new to vb.net & I have a problem that whenever user enters an alphabet he/she will receive message that only numbers are allowed. For this code.... Please help me. I shall be very thankful to you.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing

    If DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
        Dim combo As ComboBox = CType(e.Control, ComboBox)
        If (combo IsNot Nothing) Then

            RemoveHandler combo.SelectionChangeCommitted, New EventHandler(AddressOf ComboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted)

            AddHandler combo.SelectionChangeCommitted, New EventHandler(AddressOf ComboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim combo As ComboBox = CType(sender, ComboBox)
    If combo.SelectedItem = "Item1" Then
        DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value = "KG"
        DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value = "100"
        DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value = "Raw Material"
    ElseIf combo.SelectedItem = "Item2" Then
        DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value = "Liter"
        DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value = "47"
        DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value = "Raw Material"
    ElseIf combo.SelectedItem = "Item3" Then
        DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value = "Pound"
        DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value = "54"
        DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value = "Raw Material"
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Mul_Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Mul_Button.Click
    Dim s As Int16 = Convert.ToInt16(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value)
    Dim s1 As Int16 = Convert.ToInt16(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value)
    DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value = s * s1
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValidated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValidated
    Dim s As Int16 = Convert.ToInt16(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value)
    Dim s1 As Int16 = Convert.ToInt16(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value)
    DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value = s * s1
    If DataGridView1.RowCount > 0 Then
        Dim sum As Integer
        For index As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
            sum += Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(5).Value)
        Next
        TextBox1.Text = sum
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Add_Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Add_Button.Click
    If DataGridView1.RowCount > 0 Then
        Dim sum As Integer
        For index As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
            sum += Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(5).Value)
        Next
        TextBox1.Text = sum
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: On which line does the error happens? What would you rather have happen? It seems like s and s1 are converted from string to number. If the cell doesn't contain a valid number it will crash. You might want to use TryParse instead and display a proper message.

Comment: How i use try parse can u please give me the code....

Comment: You can find good example on the [documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hh1awhy(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Either wrap your code that has Convert.ToInt16() calls in them with Try/Catch blocks, or convert them to the Int16.TryParse() approach instead.

For example, this line:

```
Dim s As Int16 = Convert.ToInt16(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value)
```

Could become:

```
Dim s As Int16
Dim strValue As String = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value
If Int16.TryParse(strValue, s) Then

    ' ... do something with "s" in here ...
    ' ... continue with code...

Else
    MessageBox.Show(strValue, "Invalid Value")
End If
```

Comment: i want quantity to be in integers only which is in cell(5).

Comment: Great.  That was an example using a specific line of your code.  You'll have to implement that same pattern for each of your values, where ever it is appropriate to do so...good luck!